# GGPLOT Color won't work

Tags: r, ggplot2

It must be very simple. I just want to set the color for a scatter plot.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 df3=data.frame(cbind("A", 5, 3))
 ggplot(data = df3) + geom_point(aes(x = X2, y = X3, colour = "black"))
```

Why is it pink and not black?
I've tried with hex code as well.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr8NO.png)

Comment: Close. Move `colour="black"` outside the aesthetics mapping.

Comment: You need to put black outside the aes. Currently it's mapping the variable "black" to a colour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
df3=data.frame(cbind("A", 5, 3))
ggplot(data = df3) + geom_point(aes(x = X2, y = X3), colour = "black")
```

That's a solution to your problem. Colour should be a parameter of geom_point() function and not aes.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/3001626) for guiadance on how to post an answer when the issue was already solved in comments.

Comment: With this soulution there is no opportunity to add legend :(